# Hello, Is there a shortcut to LOOK AT?

Tags: 3d-view

Is there a shortcut to LOOK AT in Blender ??
for example In maya 'A' is the hotkey to Look at, or Alt+L in Alias to look at or zoom upto the model. For some reason I cant find the model or the obj, guess i messed up the zoom!  NEED HELP.
Thank you.

Comment: It's called "Frame Selected" in Blender. Should be Numpad . (dot) by default. You can look it up and change it in Preferences > Keymap > search for "frame selected", under 3D View.

Comment: Thanks ! I did Shift+c to recenter